# Get unique results from this function

Tags: wpdb

I want to get unique results from this function

```
global $wpdb;
$helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wc_billing_field_3465'"
);

foreach( $helloworld_id as $result ) {
    echo $result->meta_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would likely be more efficient to change your database query to

> SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wc_billing_field_3465'

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use an array to store the results, then the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to remove duplicates.

```
global $wpdb;
$billing_fields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wc_billing_field_3465'");
// define your array
$billing_fields_array = array(); 

foreach ( $billing_fields as $result ) {
    // push results to the array
    $billing_fields_array[] = $result->meta_value; 
}

// sort the unique values
$unique_billing_fields_array = array_unique($billing_fields_array);

foreach($unique_billing_fields_array as $unique_result) {
    // echo each unique value
    echo $unique_result;
}
```

I renamed `$helloworld_id` to `$billing_fields` to make things easier to read.

Comment: I got this errors

Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\ponisha\wp-content\themes\storefront\functions.php on line 106

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\ponisha\wp-content\themes\storefront\functions.php on line 108

Comment: could you solve this for me?

Comment: I edited Zachary's answer. The `//sort the unique values` line had the variable names the wrong way around.